# How do i write a structure over serial port?

Tags: c#, serialization, serial-port

I have the following structure

```
unsafe public struct usb_board
{
        UInt16 scr_id;
        UInt16 cmd_id;
        uint type;
        UInt16 size;
        UInt16 crc;
        uint [] buffer;
}
```

i need to write this entire structure to serial port.

Serial port connection as follows:

```
System.IO.Ports.SerialPort Port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM1");
Port.BaudRate = 9600;
Port.Open();
Port.WriteTimeout = 4000;
Port.Write("Some String Data");
```

The **port.Write** Method allows me to write string data,how do i pass this structure content over port? Do i have to convert the data to string format ? If so how do i achieve it? Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply Serialize it, you may use Json, or create your own serialization:

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(your_object);
System.IO.Ports.SerialPort Port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM1");
Port.BaudRate = 9600;
Port.Open();
Port.WriteTimeout = 4000;
Port.Write(json);
```

If it is hard to parse json in your device (or whatever the receiver is), you can create a serialization yourself:

```
unsafe public struct usb_board
{
   UInt16 scr_id;
   UInt16 cmd_id;
   uint type;
   UInt16 size;
   UInt16 crc;
   uint[] buffer;
   public override string ToString()
   {
       return $"{scr_id},{cmd_id},{type},{size},{crc},{string.Join(",", buffer)}";
   }
}
```

you can then use `your_object.ToString()` to Get a Comma Separated string with all your struct values, and you can separate it in your device.

Comment: Thank you,the overall logic kind of helped me ,i am not sure about the syntax what you have written is of C#. As I am a c# user,i kind of took your logic and re wrote the same code.I really appreciate your support and help.Thanks a lot.

Comment: the below sample (overriding `ToString()` must be very simple to implement. just when you use `.ToString()` of your struct, it will return all its properties separated by comma.